# gh release create -R error Invalid target_commitish parameter

Tags: github-cli

When trying to run `gh release create v0.0.1 -R https://github.com/path/to/repo` I get a an error as below.

`HTTP 400: Invalid target_commitish parameter (https://api.github.com/repos/path/to/repo/releases/generate-notes)`

The target repo is private.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--notes "example notes" resolved the issue. Full command:`  gh release create v0.0.1 -R https://github.com/path/to/repo --notes "release notes"`